# Possible bug with Bcrypt implementation on Spring

Tags: java, spring-security, bcrypt

I'm testing to move our password hash from sha-256 to sha-512 or bcrypt. For that, I've implemented a very simple test, but I've found out that with a specific rawPassword when Bcrypt tries to match it against the same rawPassword + anything else, it fails, returning true instead of false. Maybe it is related to the encoding, but I'm not sure.

```java
... 



    @Test
    public void testEncodePassword() {
            final String rawPassword = "¡Oh envidia, raíz de infinitos males y carcoma de las virtudes!";

            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

            String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(rawPassword);

            assertTrue(passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword,encodedPassword));
            assertFalse(passwordEncoder.matches("dds",encodedPassword));
            assertFalse(passwordEncoder.matches("dds"+rawPassword,encodedPassword));
            assertFalse(passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword+"something else",encodedPassword));


    }

...
```

Comment: This test PASSED with Spring Security 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

[Bcrypt has a maximum password length of 72 (*bytes*)](https://www.mscharhag.com/software-development/bcrypt-maximum-password-length). Java uses UTF-16 to encode strings, hence the password you used has a length of ~128 bytes:

```
>>> len("¡Oh envidia, raíz de infinitos males y carcoma de las virtudes!".encode('utf-16'))
128
```

If you want to support longer passwords use something different from bcrypt or you have to somehow hash the password before feeding it to bcrypt (ask on the security sites to ask for how to do this securely).

Comment: Spring Security's BCrypt implementation uses UTF-8.

Comment: @holmis83 Then apparently it has a *lower* limit than 72. The 72 is the maximum possible but some implementations support at most 50. Either way the issue is the password length